# pycharm open by terminate or desktop has different installed packages, in the same interpreter configure

Tags: python, pycharm

there is no rosbag package installed opened by DESKTOP APPLICATION:

...

requests    2.19.1  2.19.1
requests-oauthlib   1.0.0   1.0.0
requests-toolbelt   0.8.0   0.8.0
roman   2.0.0   3.0
rosdep  0.12.2  0.12.2
rosdistro   0.6.8   0.6.8
rosdistro-modules   0.6.8
rosinstall  0.7.8   0.7.8
rosinstall-generator    0.1.14
rospkg  1.1.4   1.1.4
rospkg-modules  1.1.4
...

But in terminate, it has:

...

requests    2.19.1
requests-oauthlib   1.0.0
requests-toolbelt   0.8.0
resource-retriever  1.12.4
roman   2.0.0
rosbag  1.12.13 
rosboost-cfg    1.14.3
rosclean    1.14.3
roscreate   1.14.3
rosdep  0.12.2
rosdistro   0.6.8
rosdistro-modules   0.6.8
rosgraph    1.12.13 
rosinstall  0.7.8
rosinstall-generator    0.1.14
roslaunch   1.12.13 
roslib  1.14.3
roslint 0.11.0
roslz4  1.12.13 
rosmake 1.14.3
rosmaster   1.12.13 
rosmsg  1.12.13 
rosnode 1.12.13 
rosparam    1.12.13 
rospkg  1.1.4
rospkg-modules  1.1.4
rospy   1.12.13 
rosservice  1.12.13 
rostest 1.12.13 
rostopic    1.12.13 
rosunit 1.14.3
roswtf  1.12.13 
rqt-action  0.4.9
rqt-bag 0.4.12
rqt-bag-plugins 0.4.12
rqt-console 0.4.8
rqt-dep 0.4.9
rqt-graph   0.4.9
rqt-gui 0.5.0
rqt-gui-py  0.5.0
rqt-image-view  0.4.11
rqt-joint-trajectory-controller 0.13.3
rqt-launch  0.4.8
rqt-logger-level    0.4.8
rqt-moveit  0.5.7
rqt-msg 0.4.8
rqt-nav-view    0.5.7
rqt-plot    0.4.8
rqt-pose-view   0.5.8
rqt-publisher   0.4.8
rqt-py-common   0.5.0
rqt-py-console  0.4.8
rqt-reconfigure 0.4.10
rqt-robot-dashboard 0.5.7
rqt-robot-monitor   0.5.8
rqt-robot-steering  0.5.9
rqt-runtime-monitor 0.5.7
rqt-rviz    0.5.7
rqt-service-caller  0.4.8
rqt-shell   0.4.9
rqt-srv 0.4.8
rqt-tf-tree 0.5.8
rqt-top 0.4.8
rqt-topic   0.4.10
rqt-web 0.4.8
rviz    1.12.16 
...

both of them use:  /usr/bin/python as interpreter

> How do I set to have same package?

Comment: U do something wrong. It can't be different.

Comment: I think there will be system env params mistakes, but I have no idea to solve it